# reactjs bundle script by browserify not working on the client side (Uncaught ReferenceError: Component is not defined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying out using node.js and reactjs as a template rendering service for my php backend. Here's the [guideline](https://blog.frankdejonge.nl/rendering-reactjs-templates-server-side/).

I wonder if there's a problem with my `bundle.js` built by `browserify`. I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: ItemPage is not defined` on the client side because the component `ItemPage` is not global in the `bundle.js`, but I have no idea how to access it since it is wrapped in some functions that I really don't understand.

Here's my es6 component script:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tabs from 'grommet/components/Tabs';
import Tab from 'grommet/components/Tab';
class ItemPage extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <Tabs onClick={this._onClick.bind(this)}>
            <Tab title="First Title">
                <h3>First Tab</h3>
                <p>Contents of the first tab !</p>
                <div>Something@@@@@@</div>
            </Tab>
            <Tab title="Second Title">
                <h3>Second Tab</h3>
                <p>Contents of the second tab</p>
            </Tab>
            <Tab title="Third Title">
                <h3>Third Tab</h3>
                <p>Contents of the third tab</p>
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    }
    _onClick(){
        alert("raging")
    }
}
```

The command I use to bundle the script:

```
browserify src/ItemPage.js -o /js/build/ItemPage.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]
```

Output:

```
    echo '<div id="app">';

     // reactjs markup content sent back from node.js
    echo $content;

    echo '</div>';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/build/ItemPage.js"></script>';

    echo '<script>
           var container = document.getElementById("app");
           var component = ItemPage;
           // Error!!!!
           React.renderComponent(component, container);
          </script>';
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ItemPage is not defined
```

Here is my bundle file (2mb):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XYujDUsAgtb3NrSlBFQ19qckU/view?pref=2&pli=1

You can see that ItemPage isn't global in the script.

**Update:**

I have added `default export` to the file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tabs from 'grommet/components/Tabs';
import Tab from 'grommet/components/Tab';
class ItemPage extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <Tabs onClick={this._onClick.bind(this)}>
            <Tab title="First Title">
                <h3>First Tab</h3>
                <p>Contents of the first tab !</p>
                <div>Something@@@@@@</div>
            </Tab>
            <Tab title="Second Title">
                <h3>Second Tab</h3>
                <p>Contents of the second tab</p>
            </Tab>
            <Tab title="Third Title">
                <h3>Third Tab</h3>
                <p>Contents of the third tab</p>
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    }
    _onClick(){
        alert("raging")
    }
}
export default ItemPage;
```

However ItemPage is still local and inaccessible on the client side.

Here is my latest build:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XYujDUsAgtZjNvaFdBUVlzU2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The class syntax won't create a global variable.

Comment: @gcampbell, I have just added `export default ItemPage`, but it is still not working. Please see my latest update.

Comment: The last script tag you're creating with `echo` won't have access to `ItemPage` because it's not being bundled by browserify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from adding export you need to say browserify to generate UMD output by adding `--standalone` flag.

> --standalone -s  Generate a UMD bundle for the supplied export name.
>                      This bundle works with other module systems and sets the name
>                      given as a window global if no module system is found.

```
browserify src/ItemPage.js 
        -o /js/build/ItemPage.js
        --standalone ItemPage 
        -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]
```

*multiline for the sake of readability*

Answer (score 1):

You need to export ItemPage in your script

```
export default ItemPage
```

Comment: I have add `export default ItemPage` at the end of the file and compiled it again with Browserify, but it is still not working. ItemPage is still not a global variable in my [latest built](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XYujDUsAgtZjNvaFdBUVlzU2s/view?usp=sharing)